# Why don`t I have attribute textinput?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have python 3.7 and it just doesn`t shows me textinput and numinput as an attribute. It works great with turtle.onclick() or ondrag but attributes textinput and numinput just disappeared.
How can I fix this?

```
n = turtle.Turtle()

n.speed(0)
n.penup()
n.goto(0,0)
nd = n.textinput()
```

but it doesn`t do this, it just shows me textinput as an attribute error.

Comment: Show us some code in the question. We cannot answer until we know what we are dealing with.

Comment: yea, fixed now.

Comment: Could we also see the `textinput()` function?

Comment: what do you mean? it is there.

Comment: The actual code inside of the function. `def textinput():`

Comment: Maybe you need to import Turtle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you cant call `textinput` function without parameters. Because it takes two parameter: `title` and `prompt`. And if we look for an answer of your question, we can see that in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/turtle.html#turtle.textinput) : `textinput` is not a method of `turtle.Turtle` object, it is a function of `turtle` module. So you should use it via `turtle` module:

```
import turtle
n = turtle.Turtle()

n.speed(0)
n.penup()
n.goto(0,0)
nd = turtle.textinput("","")
```